# How to set up mongoid to retry if primary goes down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a Rails 5.0 app with mongoid.  We are doing some testing by manually shutting down the primary by invoking rs.stepDown().  If we immediately edit a record, we get this error:

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (not master and slaveOk=false (13435)):
```

My specific question is how do you configure mondoid.yml to fall back to the secondary, and my generic question is, is there a way to configure mongoid to retry after a few seconds before throwing an exception?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are referring to is called "retryable writes" and it is controlled by the Ruby MongoDB driver (`mongo` gem), not Mongoid.

If the applications uses the current driver, and is running against server 3.6 or newer, no configuration is necessary - retryable writes are enabled by default.

If you are using Rails 5, according to the Mongoid compatibility table (https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-installation/#rails-compatibility) you would be using Mongoid 6.0/6.1, which are no longer supported. If you have an old version of the driver as well it may not implement retryable writes the same way current driver versions do. Ideally the driver and/or the application should be upgraded to the current driver, if this is not possible you may need to patch/backport the relevant changes into your driver version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think my issue is that retries are not being attempted, rather, I think they're being attempted but upon trying to query the secondary, are finding that the secondary has not been configured with slaveOk.  Do you think updating the driver will fix this?

Comment: One of the changes made to the driver in the last 2 years is to perform server selection before retry to get the correct server. All writes must be sent to the current primary, reads could be sent to secondaries but this must be allowed by the application's read preference.

Comment: I see, ok I will try this, to confirm, if the primary goes down, the new driver will retry (giving the secondary time to take over as the primary?)?

Comment: Yes, the driver will wait up to the server selection timeout to identify a suitable server for the retry.